# Tax Computation Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Say a product cost *a* and a tax of *x%* is applied to it, then another tax of *y%* is applied to the total. Is there a way for me to somehow "combine" the values of x% and y% so that I can do something like this:

```
a + (a * z%)
```

where z% is the combined value?

Comment: When you add $p\%$ to $a$ you get $a+(a*p/100)=a*(1+\frac{p}{100})$, so you multiply $a$ with $(1+\frac{p}{100})$. Do that twice. First with $p=x$, then with $p=y$, and you get ...

Comment: a * ( 1 + x/100) + a * ( 1 + y/100)??? I don't think it's right. For one, I think the expression is probably something like this: `(a + (a * x) ) + ((a + (a * x) ) * y)` where x and y have already been divided by 100. I want to know if it's possible to get rid of x and y and represent them as a combined value.

Comment: No, that’s not what Jyrki suggested. First you multiply by $1+\frac{x}{100}$ to get $a\left(1+\frac{x}{100}\right)$, which is an $x$% increase over $a$. Then you multiply *that* by $1+\frac{y}{100}$ to get $$a\left(1+\frac{x}{100}\right)\left(1+\frac{y}{100}\right)\,,$$ a $y$% increase over the $x$% increase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming one tax is applied to the other as well as to the original item, it is easier to start with something like `a * (1 + z%)` as the form of your tax.

So your double tax is `a * (1 + x%) * (1 + y%)`.

So the combined tax rate is `z% = x% + y% + (x% * y%)`, i.e. one tax is applied to the other as well as to the original item as in the assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Jyrki's answer is correct.  First, take the percentage, rewrite it as a decimal, and add 1 to it.  So if the tax increases the price by 5% for example, we multiply the price by 1.05.  If the other tax is 10% (and this is a strange tax that taxes tax...), we multiply it again by 1.1.  So if the original price is $a$, our new cost is

$1.1(1.05a)=(1.1\times1.05)a=1.155a$

Now, to get the percent increase, we just subtract out 1 again and write it as a percent.  The increase in cost is $.155a$, so a 5% tax and 10% tax will increase the cost by 15.5%